# Cross Browser Discrepancies On Block

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling to adjust a block on my website to be the same on Firefox as it is on Chrome and IE. I think its possibly to do with something in my block haven't a different header per block.

You can view my block here:

[The LIVESCORE | HANDY LINKS | LATEST POSTS qt block.](http://betmental.com/latest)

As you can see on Chrome and IE its fine but on Firefox its all hanging down like a saggy old lady. The tabs should be up on the same line as the breadcrumb.

I've tried for ages and for the life of me i just cant seem to sort it. I'd love it if someone could assist me and it would be very much appreciated.

```
<div id="main-wrapper-inner">
<div id="search-breadcrumb">
<div id="main" class="clearfix">
<div id="content-wrapper">
<div id="content-tops" class="clearfix">
<div id="content-top-inner" class="content-top-1 clearfix">
<div id="content-top-one" class="column">
<div class="region region-content-top-one">
<div id="block-quicktabs-latestpage" class="block block-quicktabs contextual-links-region region-count-1">
<div class="block-inner clearfix">
<div class="content">
<div id="quicktabs-latestpage" class="quicktabs-wrapper quicktabs-style-nostyle jquery-once-2-processed">
<div class="item-list">
<ul class="quicktabs-tabs quicktabs-style-nostyle">
<li class="active first">
<li>
<li class="last">
<a id="quicktabs-tab-latestpage-2" class="active ajax-processed jquery-once-3-processed" href="/latest?qt-latestpage=2#qt-latestpage">Livescore</a>
```

css

```
ul.quicktabs-tabs li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#quicktabs-latestpage ul.quicktabs-tabs li, #quicktabs-forumstuff ul.quicktabs-tabs li {
    font-family: Oswald,'Arial Narrow',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.quicktabs-tabs li {
    font-family: 'Anton',Arial Narrow,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
}
.block ul li {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
ul.quicktabs-tabs li {
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow must have code, preferably a SSCE. Q&A on this site are intended to have historical & archival value -- which just having a link elsewhere, doesn't provide. Please provide code.

Comment: Sorry Thomas code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Quicktabs UL (Livescore, Handy Links, Latest Posts) isn't inside the `<div id="search-breadcrumb">` div, it's way down inside your "content" divs.

Browser would probably find it easier & more natural to position it up by the breadcrumb, if it actually *was* up by the breadcrumb. Structuring the page sensibly would almost certainly be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks Thomas i see now why its all so bad and your right my structure is terrble. It was a bit of a hack letting the block appear in the search-breadcrumb as it is. Ive tried moving the html about but due to my themes responsivedesign im pushing blocks to being 100% width etc and its really messing my site up. I might hve a look at a browser dpecific bit of css when i get up to sort it. thanks. do you think that this could work?

Comment: Hi Reg, I tried editing a copy.. could easily move the "item list" div up into breadcrumbs & make it a float, knocked off the position:absolute and top: offsets & made it position correctly. Your CSS is full of aggressive & tangled sizing rules however, makes getting the element style correct not straightforward.. I'll leave it to you.

Comment: I didn't have to use 100% width, just float:right. Try to avoid using top: offsets and absolute positioning everywhere, and clarify/ reduce the broadness of your CSS rules.